# Soundpool does not play any sound

Tags: java, android, audio, soundpool

The edittexts don't play any sound on click. The last time I created this kind of setup it worked. Now it doesn't. What is the issue?

**Sound class:**

```
public class MySound {

    private AudioAttributes audioAttributes;
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    protected int soundClick;

    public MySound(final Context context) {
        audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(10)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();
        soundClick = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.click, 1); 
    }

    public void setEtSound(EditText editText) {
        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                soundPool.play(soundClick, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Fragment:**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

    mySound= new MySound(getActivity());
    mySound.setEtSound(etLoginUsername);
    mySound.setEtSound(etLoginPassword);

    return view;

}
```